# Python socket sending problem

Tags: python, sockets, service, connection, port

I'm currently working on a simple Python script that connects to an IP/Port and lets you preform commands. Kinda like telnet. I want it to connect to lets say MySQL(Just an example) and execute MySQL commands like you would with Telnet or NetCat.
But lets say I connect to a service, I can't execute commands. I'm trying to connect to a custom port on localhost. Let me show the code:

```
try:
    sock.connect((host, port))
    recvdata = sock.recv(socksize)
    print("Type your commands now")
    while(1): #Setting a loop
        print(recvdata)
        userInput = raw_input(">")
        sock.send(userInput + '\r\n\r\n')
        print(recvdata)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nConnection closed")
    sys.exit()
```

So this is what I get when I connect:

```
:: !Test service! ::
```

If I type anything, I just get the banner again. The same banner over and over no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `recvdata = sock.recv(socksize)` is outside of the recv loop.  I think, a good introduction to [socket programming in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/socket-intro.htm) might be helpful to you. Your previous question and this one would have been easily spotted by you using that introduction tutorial. Have a look at an example socket echo server/client ([at this site](http://effbot.org/pylib/socket.htm)), which you can modify further and proceed with your task. Run two separate terminals, run the echo server at one end and use the echo client with address pointint to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I've already tried this. That doesn't work also. I just get a bunch of unwanted output.

Comment: I've been reading it. I've tried many things such as taking `sock.connect()` out of the loop but then when I try a command it works the first time but not the second time. I keep getting a transport endpoint is connected error.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example link of small echo server and client.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no wonder. You never actually call `sock.recv` on the communicating socket after you send your input.
Prior to the loop, `recvdata` contains the "banner" from the initial `connect`. But once you're in the loop, this variable is never changed.

I believe what you want is:

```
sock.connect((host, port))
recvdata = sock.recv(socksize)
print(recvdata)
print("Type your commands now")
while(1): #Setting a loop
    userInput = raw_input(">")
    sock.send(userInput + '\r\n\r\n')
    recvdata = sock.recv(socksize)
    print(recvdata)
```